# Change date format in razor cshtml view file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, date, razor

I need some help that might be easy for all of you out there.
I have this mvc3 web app, I just need to convert the display of date format from mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM to dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM Military time. I found some solutions but it doesn't work like @item.date.ToString("dd.mm.yyyy")

can someone please? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#Y133

This worked for me in a console app:

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {

      //mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM to dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM
      var date = Convert.ToDateTime("12/13/1980 4:50:34 PM");
      Console.WriteLine(date);

      var date2 = date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
      Console.WriteLine(date2);

      Console.ReadLine();
   }
}
```

Output:

```
12/13/1980 4:50:34 PM
13.12.1980 16:50
```

Comment: date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"); - gives me this exception "Method 'ToString' has 0 parameter(s) but is invoked with 1 argument(s)." Anyway I referred to the link you have given and got the solution `[TestMethod]
        public void DateFormatting()
        {
            IEnumerable<GlobalExport> globalExport = _service.GetAllGlobalExport(1);
            foreach(var item in globalExport)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0:dd.MM.yy H:mm:ss }", item.LastExportSent);
            }
        }`

Comment: Hmmm, that probably means that the object you are ToString()'ing isn't a DateTime object -- as that has multiple overloads: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx